# Error when uploading file to Google Cloud Storage in node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, ejs, filepath

I have this form element:

```
  <form action="/upload" method="POST">
      <input type="file" id="img" name="image" accept="image/*" class="btn"/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload</button>
  </form>
```

When I submit the form, the `post` request is getting the file name of the image through body-parser.

```
app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.image);
  const filename = req.body.image;
  async function uploadFile() {
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename)
  }
  uploadFile().catch(console.error);
  res.redirect("/upload");
});
```

The `console.log` returns just the file name `image.jpg` without the path.  When the `uploadFile()` method is called it returns an error saying that the file path does not exist, because it is saying the file path is: `C:\\Users\Owner\Desktop\Serverfolder\image.jpg` which is completely wrong.

So how do I prepend the right file path that google cloud will accept?  I know that the browser will protect the actual file path for file uploads, but it is not filling in the temporary or fakepath so that the image can be uploaded.

Please help, because the google cloud documentation is annoyingly vague on the matter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path should be referenced within the scope of your server. What you can do is store the file in a folder called uploads with multer. Then reference the relative path into uploadFile() and upload it. It should get the file then. Once you've uploaded you can then use the fs node package to delete the file.

Here is the multer configuration i used

```
// Multer config
const multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'blog-images/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let tempImageName = file.mimetype.toString().split('/')[1];
        req.imageName = tempImageName
      cb(null, tempImageName)
    }
  })
  var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

And this is the code that uploads it

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res)=>{
 //blog-images below is the custom folder i created. I can easily reference it
//since it is a part of the server
  let imagePath = `blog-images/${req.imageName}`
  // The code is split here but essentially, it solves the file path problem
  uploadBlog(imagePath, req.body)
  .then( uploadRef => {
    // The fs module deletes it from the folder so you don't have to worry about
    // uncessary files
    fs.unlink(imagePath, ()=>{
      res.send('upload success')
     })
   }).catch(err => console.log(err.message))
})
```

Comment: No, but I have the fakepath directory as a preview image inside the form which is working.  Just don't know how to pass that back to the post request in my server file.

Comment: You'd have to use a middleware like multer because that's the only way you can access the req.file property where the image file is being stored.

Comment: @Tenotea I added multer and have access to req.file now, but that still doesn't make my uploadFile() function work.  I'm still getting the same error regarding the file path.   The function is copied directly from the google cloud docs...

Comment: I'm not mad, you're the only one helping me.  What you should do to avoid pissing off the moderators is to post that into an answer and show a brief demo on how to do it.

Comment: @Tenotea Thanks that looks good.  The upload works (still need to tweak it to take in the form data as the file name, etc), but I still can't get the file deletion part to work.  Right now it says `uploadBlog is not defined`. I tried to tweak it but can't get it to work.  Are you sure that part of the code is correct?  Thanks again...

Comment: The ```uploadBlog()``` function is a wrapper for the actual ```uploadFile()``` function. So you need to replace that with your actual implementation. I took the code from my blog's code so it wasn't really for your use case. How it works is what you need to take note of.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it.  I was able to implement the file deletion after image upload.  Still more to do, but that solves the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put all the header in the hidden text tag

```html
<form action="https://storage.googleapis.com/travel-maps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="test-object">
<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="https://www.example.com/success_notification.html">
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="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">
<input type="hidden" name="x-goog-algorithm" value="GOOG4-RSA-SHA256">
<input type="hidden" name="x-goog-credential" value="example_account@example_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/20191102/auto/storage/goog4_request">
<input type="hidden" name="x-goog-date" value="20191102T043530Z">
<input type="hidden" name="x-goog-signature" value="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">

<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples) for further information